# Build issue for running a iOS project in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build

[image]

I referred all possible solutions in stack overflow,I have the following

1. Valid architecture - arm64 armv7 armv7s
2. complier for c/c++/objective c   - default complier (apple LLVM 5.0)

There is no .plist duplicates and I deleted my  derived data,restarted Xcode and device,deleted app.

Still I run the same issue.My Xcode version is 5.0.
My app was running good with no issue suddenly I found this issue arising from nowhere ?

Build settings :
[image]

Comment: What device is connected? - did you clean the build folder? (option click and clean)

Comment: Are you trying to run your application in real device?

Comment: try to quit xcode and simulator then open and run again

Comment: which device of version you selected to run

Comment: @JohnWoods Yes clean and run but no use and my device is iPhone 4 (iOS 7).

Comment: @rajesh yes I'm running in iPhone 4 with iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making multiple targets. apply this

1. In each target project > Build Settings > Packaging -> Product Name
2. In your.plist use "Required device capabilities"  remove it from plist
3. arm6 architecture not support xcode 5. if you are using remove from that

Edited:

I'm not sure change standard architecture

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried all these still hanging in the same issue.I had Valid architecture - arm64 armv7 armv7s previously there was no problem.I have a un-updated duplicate of my project that is running fine with the same architecture and other things remains same.

Comment: did you post your build setting page screen shot

Comment: change standard architecture

Comment: if possible link you project

Comment: which version of simulator and device you can able to run

Comment: i could not run in any simulator and my device too.

Comment: if possible link your project

Answer (score 0):

1) In your.plist use "Required device capabilities" remove it from plist. 
Might be this will be help.